# C# passing data between forms without "Form1 frm=new Form1();"

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an Order_Form with a button that takes you to Client_form to choose there a client name. I wanted to pass the client name back to the Order_Form  (by clicking a button) but without using

```
Order_Form  frm1 = New Order_Form();
```

cause I will be lost all the data in the Order_Form. 
How can I do that?

Comment: By `take you to Client_Form` do you mean you are creating a new form? Like `Client_form cform = new Client_form();` and `cform.Show();`?

Comment: I swear this is the third day in a row I see a duplicate of that question here.

Comment: @Transcendental Lol. Cant tell for myself.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to pass the instance of the `Order_Form` to your `Client_Form`:

```
public class Order_Form : Form
{
    public Order_Form()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public string clientName = String.Empty;

    public void GetClientName()
    {
        // Pass the instance of the Order_Form
        Client_form cform = new Client_form(this);
        cform.Show();
    }
}

public class Client_form
{
    public Client_form(Order_Form instance)
    {
        // Use the passed instance to access your clientName
        instance.clientName = "your string back";
    }
}
```